# Running two instance of haproxy on the same machine

Tags: linux, haproxy

I have haproxy running on machine A. How can I create a another instance of it? (having its own configuration file). I tried to make a copy of haproxy in /etc/ with different name and added it to init.d what it did not work, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a copy of your /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.

```
cp /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/haproxy_s.cfg
```

Make sure that you don't have any conflicting ports for the frontends in this copy. At this point you can start haproxy manually by issuing the following command.

```
/usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy_s.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy_s.pid
```

- *-D* will start haproxy in daemon mode
- *-f* is the path to the configfile
- *-p* is the path to the pidfile

If you want to start the new instance of haproxy via the init script or load it during system boot you need to make a copy of the init script first.

```
cp /etc/init.d/haproxy /etc/init.d/haproxy_s
```

In addition to that you'll need to create a symbolic link to the binary of haproxy.

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/haproxy /usr/sbin/haproxy_s
```

After that you need to make the following changes to /etc/init.d/haproxy_s

```
exec="/usr/sbin/haproxy_s"
cfgfile=/etc/haproxy/haproxy_s.cfg
pidfile=/var/run/haproxy_s.pid
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/haproxy_s
```

I've tested this configuration on my RHEL 6 installation. It should be possible to port the solution to other Linux distributions with slight modifications as long as those distributions are using the init system.

Answer (score 0):

What did not work about it? Errors? Anything in the logs?

What you will need to do is copy the config file, and make some changes.

Once a port is bound by a service, that same port can not be bound by anohter until release. You will need to change your port bindings in the new config file, and then launch it specifying that new config file with `-f`.

Comment: nothing in the logs. I don't want to bind with the same port. One instance of haproxy will bind to 443 and the other one will bind to port 9090

Comment: You say _it didn't work_, what about it didn't work...? If it failes to start, there will be erros **somewhere**.

Comment: I created a copy int /etc/ name it "haproxy_s".
created a copy of it in init.d as well.
changed its config file to haproxy_s.cfg.
anything else you thing I should do?